# JAXB via maven with several schemas with empty namespaces

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

My goal is to generate Java classes from several xsd schemas.

I have four XSD files, they all have an empty namespace and I can't change them:

- SimpleTypeDefinitions (misc types referenced by all others)
- Header (referenced by the following two xsds)
- SingleRequest
- BatchRequest

SingleRequest and BatchRequest are very similar, they both contain elements with the same name. There is one generic webservice with a single XMLAny element. This can (currently) either contain a SingleRequest or a BatchRequest. This design is not in my control and can absolutely not be changed.

I would like to generate my Java classes from the xsds which worked fine for the SingleRequest. I had to include my generated classes with the `XMLSeeAlso` annotation in the single webservice-method.  Now that I have to add the BatchRequest I'm running into troubles, since they are conflicting.

My preferred solution would be to have everything in one project (and one pom.xml), and the java classes from the different xsds generated in different packages. At this point I'm happy with any solution though.

I tried many different solutions I found online (several here on SO), but none of them worked and in each one of them the XSDs were in different namespaces as far as I know. Among others i tried:

- several executions of the jaxb2-maven-plugin for each xsd file
- episodes in several ways (directly in the maven-plugin-execution, with command-line parameters in the execution, referencing the generated .episode-file)
- renaming the conflicting class names in the jaxb binding file, i still get "... is already defined" error from maven.

I use JAXB 2.2.7 and maven-jaxb2-plugin 0.9.0.

Any ideas?

EDIT1 2014-06-08:
I created sample XSD files to reproduce my Problem, i also include a sample pom.
With the included pom the Java classes get generated in different packages, but each package has a class "Header.java". This leads to the following Errors at runtime (when i try to call the webservice):

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext Caused
>   by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 5
>   counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions Two classes have the same XML
>   type name "{myService}myElement". Use @XmlType.name and
>   @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.

Header.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:complexType name="HeaderType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TimeStamp" type="xs:dateTime" nillable="false"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TimeOut" type="xs:long" default="0" nillable="true"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

SingleRequest.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:include schemaLocation="Header.xsd" />
<xs:element name="SingleRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Header" type="HeaderType"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Body">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestContent" type="RequestContentType"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="RequestContentType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" name="RequestContentId" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

BatchRequest.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:include schemaLocation="Header.xsd" />
<xs:element name="BatchRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Header" type="HeaderType"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Body">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="500" name="RequestContent" type="RequestContentType"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="RequestContentType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" name="RequestContentId" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" name="batchSpecificContent" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JAXBProblem</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>.apt_generated</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${compiler.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${compiler.target.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>2.2.7</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>2.2.9</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.0</version>
                <executions >
                    <execution>
                        <id>Header</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generateDirectory>src/generated-sources/java</generateDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>com.example.header</generatePackage>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>Header.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources</bindingDirectory>
                            <bindingIncludes>
                                <include>bindingsr.xjb</include>
                            </bindingIncludes>
                            <episode>true</episode>
                            <episodeFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/header.episode</episodeFile>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>SingleRequest</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <generateDirectory>src/generated-sources/java</generateDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>com.example.singlerequest</generatePackage>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>SingleRequest.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources</bindingDirectory>
                            <bindingIncludes>
                                <include>bindings.xjb</include>
                            </bindingIncludes>
                            <episode>false</episode>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>BatchRequest</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <generateDirectory>src/generated-sources/java</generateDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>com.example.batchrequest</generatePackage>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>BatchRequest.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources</bindingDirectory>
                            <bindingIncludes>
                                <include>bindings.xjb</include>
                            </bindingIncludes>
                            <episode>false</episode>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/generated-sources/java</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I'd need this set of 4 XML Schema files, reduced to a mininimum but demonstrating the conflict. I think it can be handled by xjc-ing files 1,2 and 3 and then, with a binding to rename the clashes, do another xjc run with 1,2 and 4. Some Java classes will be generated twice: simply let one overwrite the other.

Comment: Have you tried to generate each xsd in different packages? using ..<generatePackage>xsd1.package</generatePackage>

Comment: @Xstian yes, i tried that. When i do that, i have the header-classes in every package (since they are referenced by the others). I then cant put all my classes in the jaxb-context because they are duplicate. At least i think thats the reason. Thats why i tried episoded. Anyway, i will come up with a simple set of files to reproduce the error and post it here in a while.

Comment: i'll wait your samples to help you :)

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I've a solution but your xsd is not good.

RequestContentType in BatchRequest.xsd and RequestContentType in SingleRequest.xsd are the same Type.

If you change in this way, all work fine..

Header.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:complexType name="HeaderType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TimeStamp" type="xs:dateTime" nillable="false"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TimeOut" type="xs:long" default="0" nillable="true"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

BatchRequest.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="BatchRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Header" type="HeaderType"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Body">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="500" name="RequestContent" type="RequestContentType"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="RequestContentType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" name="RequestContentId" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" name="batchSpecificContent" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

SingleRequest.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="SingleRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Header"
                    type="HeaderType" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Body">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestContent"
                                type="RequestContentType" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Context.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:include schemaLocation="Header.xsd" />
<xs:include schemaLocation="BatchRequest.xsd" />
<xs:include schemaLocation="SingleRequest.xsd" />

</xs:schema>
```

maven plugin

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                        <arg>-nv</arg>
                    </args>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schema/integration</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <schemaInclude>Context.xsd</schemaInclude>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                    <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/schema/integration</bindingDirectory>
                    <catalog>src/main/resources/schema/integration/acme.cat</catalog>
                    <catalogResolver>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.resolver.tools.ClasspathCatalogResolver</catalogResolver>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>0.6.0</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                            <version>0.6.0</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>target/generated-sources/xjc</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I hope I've given you all the answers about your question.

Comment: Thank you for your time! Unfortunately i can't change the schemas, they are from a webservice used by several customers in different countries and it's not under my control as i said in my OP. The name conflicts are my problem, i wrote it in my question and that's why i put them in the example XSDs (there are several more elements with the same Name in the original Schema). Note: i edited the Name of the main element in single.xsd, it was a copy-paste mistake, could you please edit it in your answer as well (it's now "SingleRequest")?

Comment: I changed the answer. :) i think that you should use this xsd only to generate the classes, then you can change it. Have you tried if work fine? ... No problem for my time is a pleasure to help you.